# Postgres Advisory Locks not working

Tags: python, postgresql, locking, psql, pgbouncer

I am having issues with postgres advisory locks not acquiring correctly on postgres 9.4.4. If I ssh into a postgres server on two screens and open psql to acquire a lock on one and attempt to aquire the lock on another it works perfectly. However, if I do it from another server that is pointed to that server I am able to freely 'acquire' locks, but it never actually gets a lock from the database.

Normally, we use python to obtain a lock and that is where we initially noticed the issue. To obtain a lock manually I am using `select pg_advisory_lock(123456789);` to check which locks are out currently I am using `select objid from pg_locks where locktype = 'advisory';`

I will play it out here so you can visually see it and tell me what I am doing.

Attempting to get a lock using an app_server (remote server using pgbouncer) but it is failing.

```
app_server> psql
app_server> \c mydb
app_server> select pg_advisory_lock(123456789);
 pg_advisory_lock 
------------------

(1 row)

app_server>select objid from pg_locks where locktype = 'advisory';
 objid 
-------
(0 rows)
```

Using db_server to get a lock, then trying to get the lock again on app_server (remote) but on the same db.

```
db_server> psql
db_server> \c mydb
db_server> select pg_advisory_lock(123456789);
 pg_advisory_lock 
------------------

(1 row)

db_server> select objid from pg_locks where locktype = 'advisory';
   objid   
-----------
 123456789
(1 row)
```

Here you can see that db_server has the lock so I will now go back to app_server and attempt to get the same lock but this time it will work as expected where it will wait for the unlock from db_server.

```
app_server> select pg_advisory_lock(123456789);
...
```

Meanwhile, I will go unlock it from db_server.

```
db_server> select pg_advisory_unlock(123456789);
```

Immediately app_server gets and releases the lock.

```
servers> select objid from pg_locks where locktype = 'advisory';
 objid 
-------
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the broken servers were using `transaction` based connections to postgres while the working servers were using `session` based connections in the `pgbouncer.ini`. Not sure how this was missed in our initial look at the ini.

```
; When server connection is released back to pool:
;   session      - after client disconnects
;   transaction  - after transaction finishes
;   statement    - after statement finishes
pool_mode = session
```

Comment: Yep. Transaction pooling in pgbouncer does not play well with session-level features like advisory locks.

Comment: That makes total sense. I am not sure why those servers were set on that, the rest were set to session.